# How to ensure user has lifted up the phone to eye-level?

Tags: user-behavior, instructions

We are creating an app wherein we need to detect that the person has lifted the phone up to eye-level. Something like this photo below: [image]

We were thinking to use the camera to detect the face (as in a selfie) however, a person can still take a photo of his face from below (without lifting his arms to this level) so it's not so optimal.

I wonder what methods we can use or what instruction to give to ensure that this has been done by the user.

Comment: You will never be able to know if it's "done by the user": someone else could hold the phone, or a robot could. Or user could be holding the phone up to someone else's eyes.

Comment: I knew something was on my mind... What if the user lays on the floor (looking up to the sky being on their back, or, as the opposite, looking right to the horizon being on their belly)?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the front camera for taking the photo and display contours of the eye area on the screen overlaying the image of the persons face while taking the selfie.

That way the user has a visual guide to take the a proper picture.

Bonus points for giving the user visual feedback as soon as he is holding the camera in the right way (green contours).